# Python version of Matlab Signal Toolbox's tfestimate()?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

Is there a Python version of Matlab's tfestimate()? I have looked into the control toolbox but it only offers linear transfer functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As shown in the 'more about' section of the [help of tfestimate](http://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tfestimate.html), the transfer function is calculated more or less as `Txy = Pyx / Pxx`, so by dividing the cross-spectral-density between `y` and `x` by the power-spectral-density of `x`. Note that for calculating the cross-spectral density, the order of the arguments is important, since `Pyx` is calculated (after appropriate windowing and normalization) as the average of `fft(y) * conj(fft(x))` over the individual windows. Similarly, the PSD `Pxx` is calculated as averaging `fft(x) * conj(fft(x))`. I forgot exactly why, but there is a good reason why you calculate it as the ratio between these two averages, instead of directly averaging `fft(y) / fft(x)`.

Both cpsd and psd are available in [matplotlib.mlab](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html), so you can calculate a transfer function more or less like this (untested):

```
from matplotlib.mlab import psd, csd

def tfe(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
   """estimate transfer function from x to y, see csd for calling convention"""
   return csd(y, x, *args, **kwargs) / psd(x, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sadly making a TF is not as simple as you mentioned Bas. The TF using the method you provided, the result from Python gives the 'squished' (smaller dB range) and positive mirror image across the x axis of Matlab's output. Matlab gives dB in negative space and Python gives dB in positive space.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that the algorithm is correct, you can check for yourself in Matlab: for me `[tf1, f] = tfestimate(x, y, hann(nfft), nfft/2, nfft, fsample)` and `[Pyx, f] = cpsd(y, x, hann(nfft), nfft/2, nfft, fsample); [Pxx, f] = pwelch(x, hann(nfft), nfft/2, nfft, fsample); tf2 = Pyx ./ Pxx` yield exactly (not even numerical errors!) the same result for some test data. I might have screwed up some detail in the Python code, will have to check later. Did you try to swap the arguments?

Comment: I just tried what you had above and got a positive mirror image (with some error, mostly on the low end of the frequency range) of the output given by tfestimate. So I am not sure what else is going on under the hood for Matlab's function.

Comment: Are you sure you are not swapping `x` and `y`? Since in that case, you will get the inverse transfer function, so the absolute value of the TF will be the negative when measured in dB.

Comment: Ah! I did accidentally swap it. Good catch. I redid the python with the code you suggested but the result is showing a shrunken version when compared to Matlab's tfestimate output.

I tried doing the cross and auto power spectral densities a different way using 

scipy.signal.welch

Comment: Here is the code:
`freq, psd = scipy.signal.welch(x = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(in1=x, in2=x, mode='full'), fs, window=signal.hann(nfft, sym=False), noverlap=nfft/2, nfft=nfft, scaling='density', return_onesided='True')`

and

`freq, csd = scipy.signal.welch(x = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(in1=y, in2=x, mode='full'), fs, window=signal.hann(nfft, sym=False), noverlap=nfft/2, nfft=nfft, scaling='density', return_onesided='True')`

and then finally

`tfe = csd / psd`

which matches exactly except for a few peaks in the lower and mid frequency range. Any ideas?

Comment: I have never used `scipy.welch`, might be a new function. But I am not sure if the trick you do with `fftconvolve` is valid, according to the manual, of `welch`, the `x` argument should be a time-series. I guess a proper `csd` is not yet implemented in Scipy, that is why I always used the ones from `matplotlib.mlab`.

Comment: I can reproduce results from Matlab's tfestimate() if I use: `csd(x, y, *args, **kwargs) / psd(x, *args, **kwargs)`, i.e. switching the arguments to csd(). Failing to do so, I find that the im-part of the transfer function values are all negated, except the DC (the first element). If you're only interested in the magnitude it makes no difference, of course.